# Weird radio buttons display for Angular Reactive Forms with Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular8, angular-material-table

I have three rows of radio button on a Material Table. However, it only shows one checked for all of them. Although I can modify the data of the radio buttons.

[image]

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>{{ name }}</h1>
<form name="testForm" [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
  <div formArrayName="radioButtons">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="testForm.controls['radioButtons'].controls">        
      <ng-container matColumnDef="radioButtons">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="radio">Radio Buttons</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i" class="radio">            
          <mat-radio-group name="radio" formControlName="radio" required disableOptionCentering>
            <mat-radio-button value="Y">Yes</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button value="N">No</mat-radio-button>
          </mat-radio-group>            
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="classGridDisplayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: classGridDisplayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <pre>{{ testForm.value | json }}</pre>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular2+ Reactive Form';
  testForm: FormGroup;
  classGridDisplayedColumns = [
    "radioButtons"
  ];
  data = {
    radioButtons: [
      {radio: 'Y'},
      {radio: 'N'},
      {radio: 'N'}
    ]
  };
  constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder){
    this.testForm = this.fb.group({
      radioButtons: this.fb.array(
        this.data.radioButtons.map(radioButton => this.generateRadioButtons(radioButton))
      )
    });
  }

  private generateRadioButtons(radioButton) {
    return this.fb.group({
      radio: [ radioButton.radio, Validators.required ],      
    })
  }
}
```

You can have a look at the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular2-reactive-form-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `name` attribute. Or you can use dynamic names like `name="radio{{i}}"`.

```
<h1>{{ name }}</h1>
<form name="testForm" [formGroup]="testForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
  <div formArrayName="radioButtons">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="testForm.controls['radioButtons'].controls">        
      <ng-container matColumnDef="radioButtons">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="radio">Radio Buttons</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i" class="radio">            
          <mat-radio-group formControlName="radio" required disableOptionCentering>
            <mat-radio-button value="Y">Yes</mat-radio-button>
            <mat-radio-button value="N">No</mat-radio-button>
          </mat-radio-group>            
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="classGridDisplayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: classGridDisplayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <pre>{{ testForm.value | json }}</pre>
</form>
```

Comment: @DaleNguyen You are welcome. You are using `formControlName="radio"` for all of three. If you are getting value back, it might be same for all three. What I suggest is to push one control to your reactive form for each row.

Comment: it will go from radioButons > index(0,1,2) > radio, so the value is different as you can see in the output of the form. When you change the value of a row, it will only change the value of that specific row.